# fmt.Sscanf for structs

Tags: go, scanf

I have data which was previously serialized as `fmt.Sprintf("%+v", d)`, `d` being a `struct` instance. Is there a way to scan it back? My naive attempt of using `fmt.Sscanf()` below is failing ([Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/AfscLorFFG)).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type data struct {
    f int
}

func main() {
    x := data{1}
    s := fmt.Sprintf("%+v", x)
    var y data
    n, err := fmt.Sscanf(s, "%+v", &y)
    fmt.Printf("s=%s, n=%d, err=%+v, y=%+v\n", s, n, err, y)
}
```

The output is:

```
s={f:1}, n=0, err=can't scan type: *main.data, y={f:0}
```

Is there a way to scan the struct back?

Comment: I think it is quite difficult to implement the scanner (even your own) for example when the struct has a `string` member, since the `(S)printf` will not escape the value. As an example, the `struct {s string}{" f:3"}`, will be printed as `{s: f:3}`, which is the same as the printed version of `struct{s string, f int}{"", 3}` (comma is added in the `struct` for clarity).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the `fmt` package doesn't produce strictly parseable output. Thankfully go has other packages for marshaling data which should be just as easy to use.

I'd recommend [`json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) for something simple:

```
s, err := json.Marshal(data)
// Check err
err = json.Unmarshal(s, data)
```

[`json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) will produce output which is somewhat similar to printf, but conforming to a standard which ensures it can be parsed. If your goal is to parse data that exists only in `Printf`'d form you may be out of luck.

Comment: Sure, json was my first option, but that part is somewhat performance-sensitive, so I ended up using [`gob`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/).